# Do kundalini reaches sahastra during sukshma samadhi?

Tags: vedanta, chakras, samadhi

It is well-known that thoughts cease to exist during samadhi. It can be achieved in different ways after a long sadhana.

This question is about sukshma samadhi which is experienced by every human daily. But they are unrecognized by her due to several reasons. One among them is the infinitesimal property of time of samadhi.

You can read in detail about sushma samadhis in Tripura Rahasya

> Thus requested, Janaka replied:
>
> "Listen, O Brahmin! the following are instances of that state: when a
> man remains unaware of 'in and out' for a short interval and is not
> overpowered by the ignorance of sleep; the infinitesimal time when one
> is beside one-self with joy; when embraced by one's beloved in all
> purity; when a thing is gained which was intensely longed for but
> given up in despair; when a lonely traveller moving with the utmost
> confidence is suddenly confronted with the utmost danger; when one
> hears of the sudden death of one's only son, who was in the best of
> health, in the prime of life, and at the apex of his glory. There are
> also intervals of Samadhi, namely the interim period between the
> waking, dream and sleep states; at the time of sighting a distant
> object, the mind holding the body at one end projects itself into
> space until it holds the object at the other end, just as a worm
> prolongs itself at the time of leaving one hold to catch another hold.
> Carefully watch the state of mind in the interval.
>
> [[4-14, 17, Tripura Rahasya]](https://scriptures.ru/tripura2.htm)

Afaik, a sadhaka whose kundalini reaches sahastra can only achieve samadhi. But, is it same with the sushma sadhi? Does kundalini reaches sahastra during those infinitesimal time and then returns back to muladhara instantly during sushma samadhi?

Answer (score 0):

The concept of kundalini reaching sahasrara during sukshma samadhi is a belief within some esoteric schools of Hinduism and Tantra. According to this belief, kundalini is a spiritual energy that lies dormant at the base of the spine (muladhara) and, when awakened, travels up the spine to the crown of the head (sahasrara) through a series of energy centers (chakras). The awakening of kundalini and its ascent to the sahasrara is said to bring about spiritual liberation and enlightenment.

However, the concept of sukshma samadhi and whether kundalini reaches sahasrara during these brief moments is not universally accepted in Hinduism and is a matter of debate among scholars and practitioners. Some believe that these brief experiences are glimpses of the deep meditative state known as samadhi, while others believe that they are simply moments of heightened awareness or consciousness.

The interpretation of sukshma samadhi, as described in the Tripura Rahasya, is one of many perspectives within Hinduism, and its teachings may or may not be accepted as valid by all practitioners. Ultimately, the interpretation of spiritual experiences, including the relationship between sukshma samadhi and the awakening of kundalini, is a personal and subjective matter, shaped by individual beliefs and experiences.